# shell script 'for d in "$mydirectory" ' does not 'do' for all directories in mydirectory

Tags: for-loop, sh, glob

I would like to go through all subfolders in the folders fpath and use the subfolder as a variable.

I tried:

```
#!/bin/sh -f

fpath="/folder/myfolder/*"

for d in "$fpath"
do
    subf="$d"
    echo "$subf"
done
```

but it only takes fpath for d.

what do I need to change to make it work?

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Shell globbing isn't done inside quotes, so you want do use:

```
fpath="/folder/myfolder"
for d in "$fpath"/*
```

You're also using:

```
#!/bin/sh -f
```

Which means:

```
 -f noglob
         Disable pathname expansion.
```

Not sure where you go this from, but you obviously want to drop it as well.

**Bonus hint**: you probably want to use `set` instead of setting these parameters with the hashbang, since that way they're *always* recognised, even if you do `sh test.sh`